# Make the links work only on descendant children but exclude their empty space

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, anchor

I have this structure right now

```html
<section id="mainNews" class="box_news box_red">
  <h1 class="headerBox headerBox_tri">news</h1>
  <div>
    <a href="www.site.com/news"><img src="img/content/news1.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a href="www.site.com/news">
      <h1 class="newsTitle">news 1 title</h1>
    </a>
    <p class="newsDate">14 july 1987</p>
    <a href="www.site.com/news">
      <p class="newsDetail">sample text</p>
    </a>
  </div>
</section>
```

Is there any way I turn this structure to something like this but make the link works only on its descendant children not on empty spaces

I mean the links only works on .newsTitle, .newsDetail and img

```html
<section id="mainNews" class="box_news box_red">
  <h1 class="headerBox headerBox_tri">news</h1>
  <a href="www.site.com/news">
    <img src="img/content/news1.jpg" alt="">
    <h1 class="newsTitle">news 1 title</h1>
    <p class="newsDate">14 july 1987</p>
    <p class="newsDetail">sample text</p>
  </a>
</section>
```

How can I exclude this empty space?

Thanks

Comment: `a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}` only solution i think.

Comment: @charlietfl hover right front of link in first snippet

Comment: `section a * {
  float:left;
  clear: both;
}`  ?

Comment: what does it mean? float?? I cant understand how float can trigger event differently

Comment: You can't exclude the empty space from being clicked because it's part of the `<a>` element

Comment: @JosanIracheta it may have some js solution

Answer (score 2):

Not sure it will fit all your needs but try in CSS:

```
section a * {
      float:left;
      clear: both;
    }
```

```css
section a * {
  float:left;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<section id="mainNews" class="box_news box_red">
  <h1 class="headerBox headerBox_tri">news</h1>
  <a href="www.site.com/news">
    <img src="img/content/news1.jpg" alt="">
    <h1 class="newsTitle">news 1 title</h1>
    <p class="newsDate">14 july 1987</p>
    <p class="newsDetail">sample text</p>
  </a>
</section>
```

Comment: And better add `section>a {
      display: block;
    }`

Comment: hmmm, brilliant

Comment: @pedram Sorry but this has different behaviour, isn't it?

Comment: The is only solution , but i recommend to OP, this is bad idea to wrap the anchor to all elements.. this is my opinion

Comment: its correct actually but It interfer with my own css so Im looking for another solution, js probably

Comment: very clever solution

Comment: @A.Wolff Kinda. when you  do `float` to children parent height will lost, *in inspect element* can feel this. it works without display block, but better add clear both or display block.

Comment: what if I want to exclude the date from linking?

Comment: @CameronA I have no idea why you want to do this, but maybe you forced, but i'm talking about *good html writing* usually no one do this. Yes, better wrap anchor just for `img` `h tags` , not `text` `date` or etc. Maybe can say it  even better for `SEO` case.